# making a boot able stick

Tags: boot, usb

I am trying to down load to a memory stick ubuntu 12.04 32 bit version but only seem to be able to get the 13.10 version. I think I am following the make a bootable stick instructions correctly but the page that comes up is not like the screen shots in the instructions.

Comment: where do I save the ubbuntu ISO image. I have a Toshiba NB200 netbook which runs windows xp I dont want to put it onto the net book because if I do something wrong I wont know how to correct it. would I save it onto the usb stick? . Sorry I think I might have posted in the wrong place just now

Comment: Please add a link to the instructions you are trying to follow and where you can't follow them any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-i386.iso) iso image, and next download [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and write the iso image to your USB pendrive with Unetbootin. You have to format first the pendrive to FAT32. What operating system do you use for writing the USB pendrive, is it Windows?

Comment: where do I save the ubbuntu ISO image. I have a Toshiba NB200 netbook which runs windows xp I dont want to put it onto the net book because if I do something wrong I wont know how to correct it. would I save it onto the usb stick?

Comment: There is no danger in saving any iso image on your hdd. Just save it on desktop then write it on the pendrive with Unetbootin for Windows. When you open Unetbootin check the field saying **Disk Image** then mount your downloaded Ubuntu iso image with the **...** button. Next, be careful to choose your USB drive letter listed at the bottom of the window (Unetbootin does it automatically but check it anyway) and press OK. Wait untill it is finished and then reboot. Boot into the live session, do not install Ubuntu from the boot menu. No change will be made to your WINXP installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from here: [Alternative Downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads). To create a bootable USB stick use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net). It's simple: select DiskImage, choose your downloaded ISO image of Ubuntu and your USB drive and click OK. Then wait until it's done and restart your computer when prompted. Boot from USB.

Answer (score 0):

You can download ubuntu 12.04 from http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ on your windows xp PC.(no harm)

You can use universal USB installer software on windows to make a bootable linux USB stick.Here is the link: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/